# Show custom pop up warning message when user changes any value (text box/LOV) on page

Tags: oracle-adf, adfs2.0, adfs

I have requirement to show custom pop up warning message when user changes any value (text box/LOV) on page and close tab/cancel button by mistake.

Option I tried are:

a) Within application we are using a complex task flow/RegionModel for 7 different scenario's. Also requirement is to display custom message - Hence could not use approach "unsaveddatawarning"

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/unsaveddatawarning-100139.html

b) Second option I tried was to have custom region controller:
CustomRegionController implements RegionController

Inside validateRegion(RegionContext regionContext) thought to find if page data is dirty

```
     AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getDirtyPageHandler().isDataDirty();
```

or

```
    DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCDataControl cDataControl = dcBindings.getDataControl();
    boolean dirtyFlag = cDataControl.isTransactionModified();
```

In both scenario it always gives true (seems due to common set of VO/View Link application module always gets dirty when data is being rendered on page load).

Last option I am left with is to invoke valueChangeListener for each element (textbaox, LOV, Check box). I do not like this option at all. Please suggest if there can be better way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Why is using a value change listener a problem? Have each input component call the same VCL method in the backing bean. If necessary you can get the component id from the vcl event object.